# How to create an empty lagom project using sbt step by step?

Tags: lagom

according to the lagom reference, i can use`activator new xxx lagom-java` to create a simple project.
but how to create an empty lagom project(dont include sample code) by using sbt or activator?
please show me the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following sbt plugin to achieve this :
https://github.com/Fabszn/scaffolding-plugin-lagom